# Is it undefined in C11 to modify the result of a function call, or access it after the next sequence point?

Tags: c, c99, c11

At [C99§6.5.2.2p5](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1256.html#6.5.2.2p5) there's this little gem, bolded by me for the purpose of emphasizing the question:

> If the expression that denotes the called function has type pointer to function returning an object type, the function call expression has the same type as that object type, and has the value determined as specified in 6.8.6.4. Otherwise, the function call has type void. **If an attempt is made to modify the result of a function call or to access it after the next sequence point, the behavior is undefined.**

This allowed us to return `structs`, for example:

```
struct foo { int foo;
             char bar[2]; };

struct foo get_foo() {
    struct foo return_value = { .foo = 42,
                                .bar = "x" };
    return return_value;
}
```

... and assign that return value somewhere else from within the caller, for example:

```
int main(void) {
    struct foo bar = get_foo(); /* Well defined because the return value
                                 * is copied -before- the sequence point
                                 * that terminates its storage duration */
    printf("%s\n", bar.bar);
    printf("%d\n", get_foo().foo); /* Again, well defined because the access
                                    * occurs before the next sequence point
                                    * (the function call). */
}
```

... whilst rendering examples like the following invalid:

```
int main(void) {
    printf("%s\n", get_foo().bar); /* UB because there's a sequence point
                                    * between the evaluation of the sub-
                                    * expression `get_foo().bar` and the
                                    * entrace to the function `printf` */
    get_foo().bar[0]++; /* UB because an attempt is made to modify the
                         * result of a function call */
}
```

--

[C11§6.5.2.2p5](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p5), however, is essentially the same paragraph but without the bolded text.

> If the expression that denotes the called function has type pointer to function returning an object type, the function call expression has the same type as that object type, and has the value determined as specified in 6.8.6.4. Otherwise, the function call has type void.

---

Are those examples above that are undefined behaviour in C99 still undefined in C11? If so, which paragraphs invalidate them? If not, I gather there must be some extension of the storage duration of automatic values/objects returned; which section of the standard specifies that extension of storage duration?

Comment: In C11 there is the definition of *temporary lifetime* in 6.2.4 p8 that is relevant, here.

Comment: @JensGustedt I'm not sure whether it'd be good etiquette to answer my own question with advice given by somebody else in the form of a comment without asking first, so I guess I'll ask... If you can't be bothered injecting that into an answer so I can accept it, would you mind if I do?

Comment: I think on SO there is no major problem in answering your own question. I just have put it in a comment, because I'll don't have time today to make it a decent answer. So please go ahead.

Comment: @JensGustedt If you would be so kind, I'll be interested in your critique of my answer...

Comment: Are you sure `printf("%s\n", get_foo().bar);` is UB?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ["The order of evaluation of the function designator, the actual arguments, and subexpressions within the actual arguments is unspecified, but there is a sequence point before the actual call."](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1256.html#6.5.2.2p10) So along-side C99p5 (quoted in the question), any access to `get_foo().bar` that `printf` causes will be UB.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler My bad. In C99 it is UB (due to the sequence point I mentioned). In C11, as pointed out by Jens in a comment for my answer, it is not.

Comment: Given that in your example, `get_foo().bar` is a `char *`, there probably is UB in C99 — because the pointed at material might have 'gone away'.  I'm not sure that there'd be a problem if it was an `int` though; a copy of the value would have been pushed onto the stack for `printf()`, and it doesn't matter any more what happens to the structure of the result at the sequence point because the argument is evaluated before the sequence point.  But that's rather fine reading of the material and I'm not willing to be dogmatic either way about it, especially since the standard changed with C11.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Right; if `get_foo().bar` were an `int` (and of course, the format specifier were changed to correspond) then there would be no undefined behaviour in either C99 or C11. I'd be interested in your critique of my answer, too... :)

Comment: I think that the issue of the type of `get_foo().bar` should be made much clearer in the question — it changes things in quite important ways. Maybe you would need to contrast it with `int baz;` in the same structure type.  I certainly didn't pick up on the significance of the type of `bar` until much later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are those examples above that are undefined behaviour in C99 still undefined in C11?

The examples posed above that are well defined are still well defined.

The temporary lifetime of the object in this one "ends when the evaluation of the *containing full expression or declarator* ends", so this previously undefined example is now well defined:

```
printf("%s\n", get_foo().bar);
```

This example is still undefined behaviour, because an attempt is made to modify an object that has temporary lifetime:

```
get_foo().bar[0]++;
```

> If so, which paragraphs invalidate them? If not, I gather there must be some extension of the storage duration of automatic values/objects returned; which section of the standard specifies that extension of storage duration?

As pointed out by Jens Gustedt in a comment, [C11§6.2.4p8](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.2.4p8) seems to convey a slightly different meaning to the sentence that C99§6.5.2.2p5 contains which C11§6.5.2.2p5 omitted:

> A non-lvalue expression with structure or union type, where the structure or union contains a member with array type (including, recursively, members of all contained structures and unions) refers to an object with automatic storage duration and temporary lifetime.<sup>36)</sup> Its lifetime begins when the expression is evaluated and its initial value is the value of the expression. Its lifetime ends when the evaluation of the containing full expression or full declarator ends. Any attempt to modify an object with temporary lifetime results in undefined behavior.
>
> <sup>36)</sup> The address of such an object is taken implicitly when an array member is accessed.

It seems that a little reorganisation was performed; the "storage duration extension" sentence in C99 was changed and moved from the "function call" section to the "storage duration" section, where it fits better.

The only question remaining is whether or not the *result of a function call* is considered an *lvalue*. For every operator that produces an lvalue, it seems as though it is explicitly mentioned that the operator produces an lvalue. For example, [C11§6.5.3.2p6](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.5.3.2p6) states that the unary `*` operator produces an lvalue providing its operand points at an object.

The *function call* operator, however, says nothing about producing an lvalue, so we must assume that it doesn't produce an lvalue. If that's not good enough, then consider [C11§6.5.2.3p3](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#6.5.2.3p3) and p7, which say:

> A postfix expression followed by the `.` operator and an identifier designates a member of a structure or union object. The value is that of the named member,<sup>95)</sup> and is an lvalue if the first expression is an lvalue.
>
> If `f` is a function returning a structure or union, and `x` is a member of that structure or union, `f().x` is a valid postfix expression but is not an lvalue.

We can also deduce from these two paragraphs that the result of a function is not an lvalue, thus meeting the criteria for C11§6.2.4p8 (quoted above).

*Footnote 95 is interesting but tangential to the discussion on hand:*

> <sup>95)</sup> If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to
> store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted
> as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type
> punning’’). This might be a trap representation.

Comment: Actually, I don't think that your answer is correct. You missed the subtlety of *full expression*. The expressions that provide function arguments are part of a larger expression, the function call. So they are not full expressions. Thus with C11 passing a pointer to object with temporary lifetime to a function is valid, as long as that function doesn't modify that object.

Comment: @JensGustedt Ahh, indeed I did miss that! Thanks for your critical analysis. I have made corrections... Hopefully I got it right this time :P

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help, Jens and Jonathan!